# How could Geordi possibly know how long it would take for the Borg to be destroyed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

In "I, Borg," while working on the invasive program designed to destroy the Borg, Geordi tells Captain Picard that within a few months the entire Borg Collective should be wiped out. How could he possibly know this? The Federation couldn't have any knowledge of the size of the Borg at this point. And even if they did, how could they possibly know how quickly the program would take to work? Geordi is smart, but I don't recall him owning a crystal ball.

What is the canon answer to this?

Answer (score 7):

Exponential growth is really quite powerful: even a simply doubling from one once per day would get you to over a billion in one month, and 2,475,880,078,570,760,000,000,000,000 (2 billion billion billion!) in three months.

Even if infected Borg are eventually detected because they become "broken", and then disconnected from the collective, there would still be a massive growth - as long as each infected Borg can subsequently infect more than one other.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the maximum speed of subspace communications and the throughput (bit-rate) at that speed, the size of the galaxy and the infection rate, you can extrapolate a rough date by which all the Borg should be infected.  This is much like the rough calculation Spock (and later Dax) made about the number of tribbles on space station K7.

> **SPOCK**: They seem to be gorged.
>
> **BARIS**: Gorged?  On my grain?!  Kirk, I am going to hold you responsible.  There must be thousands of them.
>
> **KIRK**: Hundreds of thousands.
>
> **SPOCK**: One million, seven hundred seventy-one thousand, five hundred sixty-one.  That's assuming one tribble multiplying with an average litter of ten, producing a new generation every twelve hours over a period of three days.

Comment: "One million, seven hundred seventy-one thousand, five hundred sixty-one" < is a very specific rough calculation...

Comment: @HorusKol - and actually too specific if you're going off 10^6.  We may not know the original number of tribbles, but the answer should end in a 0 at the very least.  I guess this is what happens when Vulcans assume things.

Comment: @Tim You're forgetting the tribble that you started with.  Each generation is a power of 11.  1,777,561 is 11^6.

Comment: @HorusKol: That number could be a (precise) outcome of a calculation which is based on estimated numbers; therefore still being an estimate.

Comment: @Flater - true, but a general rule of estimation is that precision and accuracy have an inverse relationship

Comment: @HorusKol: "precision and accuracy have an inverse relationship" => **when both are applied to the same number**, yes. The **outcome** of a mathematical calculation is not an estimation. It is a very precise outcome. However, the **input** of the calculation could be an estimation. If I estimate that there are 500 unique visitors to this site every day, and 1100 questions get posted per day (both are estimates), then on average, a user will post **2.2** questions per day. Notice that the outcome is **more precise** than my initial estimates, but not more accurate, as it is based on them.

Comment: @Flater it is actually illogical to be so precise with such rough initial estimates - it would be better to say between 2 or 3 questions per day, or approximately 1.7 million troubles... But that would have ruined the gag in the episode much as this combo ruined my gag...

Comment: @HorusKol: It's not illogical. Keep in mind, the calculation of tribble spawning is of an **exponential** nature, which can _very_ quickly devolve into non-trivial numbers. Example, I put $100 in my bank account, at 10% compound interest. How much do I have in my account after 10 years? **$259.37**. I used multiples of 10, and the answer is still unexpectedly precise and complex. While my initial values all had a low **precision**, the **outcome** of the calculation has a **high(er) precision**. Yet; the outcome of my calculation can only be as **accurate** as the input. It can never increase.

Comment: @HorusKol: Spock even specifically mentions how he estimated it; what the calculation is based on. Spock has no issues in doing mental arithmetic (hence the incredibly precise answer), but he cannot accurately tell you how many tribble there were to begin with. No one knows, it is not a matter of being proficient at math. The only reason why you would say "around 1.7 million" is if you were either incapable or indifferent to do the whole calculation. _Spock is not estimating the calculation, he is estimating the numbers that are put into the calculation_. And that is a big difference.